# Export mailboxes from Exchange 2003, but only from 1 mailstore

Tags: exchange-2003

Anyone know of a good way to limit an EXMERGE (to pst's) to only one mailstore?  Our exchange server has a few thousand accounts but I only want to export about 80 that are all contained in one mailstore.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, when you run exmerge only select the mailstore that you want to export the mailboxes from.

Comment: Where is that selection?  the only options I see are for the server.

Comment: When you click next you'll see a database selection window.

Comment: OK.  I'm an idiot.  EXMerge has that selection.  Mail Migration does not.